# Why does containsAll return false?

Tags: java

Why does this code evaluate to false?

**code**:

```
String[] a = {"donald,duck"};
String[] b = {"duck,donald"};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).containsAll(Arrays.asList(b)));
```

**output**:

```
false
```

From the [docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> boolean containsAll(Collection c)
>   Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

**Update**: Realized the flaw as soon as the first answer ticked in. I'll go and sit in the corner for a while now, thanks. *equips hat of shame*

Comment: Because `"donald,duck"` is one string, and `{"donald,duck"}` is not the same as `{"donald","duck"}`.

Comment: No shame, it happens. It may have been a silly mistake but at least it was a well-constructed question (if off-topic due to typo nature).

Comment: I am unable to delete it since it contains answers, but thank you. :)

Comment: just another "goofy" error :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `"donald,duck".equals("duck,donald")` is `false`, hence the result. You've 2 arrays with 1 elements each.